# Apache HttpClient 4.5 or Java HttpsURLConnection - Many instances execute GET, POST with Threads in parallel, time increase

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to run many `GET` and `POST`. In this example I use `GET` and for every task the same `URL`, but later it will be always a different `URL` for each task.

What I find that the time increases as the number of task and threads used.

```
num = 1   ->  Done in  1846
num = 10  ->  Done in  2114
num = 100 ->  Done in  7204
num = 200 ->  Done in 13720
```

If I have just 1 task I use 1 thread. If 10 tasks I use 10 threads, and so on.

I don't understand the time increase. If time for 1 task executed with 1 thread would take approx. 1 second, then for 10 tasks executed with 10 threads I would expect about the same time of 1 sec. Because on my `4-core CPU` I can executed many threads concurrently.

Is it possibly that because I have only 1 network device, the requests don't get send in parallel but somehow in sequence?

```
// Amount of task and threads
int num = 10;

// Create many instances of the task
List<MyCallable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
// Create num instances of MyCallable

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(num);
List<Future<Void>> invokeAll = null;

long started = System.currentTimeMillis();

try {
    invokeAll = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
}

long ended = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Done in " + (ended - started));

executor.shutdown();


private class MyCallable implements Callable<Void> {
    public MyCallable() {}

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
       int statusCode = sendGet();
       return null;
    }

    private int sendGet() throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = closeableHttpClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://bing.com")); // https://www.google.com
            
        int statusCode = closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            
        closeableHttpClient.close();
            
        return statusCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: You create a new default client for every task. Don’t! Set a sensible connection pooling configuration and use the same client. You’re basically concluding that cars are slow because you’re building a new one for every journey…

Comment: How? In this example I use Apache HttpClient. But I also use Java HttpsURLConnection, because I have to set a hostname verifier. I'm aksing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68300766/spring-boot-2-5-java-15-httprequest-and-httpclient-check-cn-of-target-certif for a solution so I can use Java HttpClient, pershaps also Apache HttpClient.

Comment: For every URL I use, in this example I use for asking purposes bing.com or google.com, I create a HttpsURLConnection and on this I set the hostname verifier. I don't know if this is possible with a pooling configuration.